# EF 4 deleting related items before the entity is saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lets say I have the following two entities:

```
Item
 int Id
 ICollection<ChildItem> ChildItems

ChildItem
 int Id
 Item ParentItem
```

(a cascade on delete is set from Item to ChildItem, both in EF designer and on the SQL server)
and I have some code like this:

```
Item newItem = new Item();
ChildItem child1 = new ChildItem();
ChildItem child2 = new ChildItem();
newItem.ChildItems.Add(child1);
newItem.ChildItems.Add(child2);
myContext.Items.AddObject(newItem);
// Then much, much further down the line
myContext.Items.DeleteObject(newItem);
```

Now, does EF automatically figure out it also has to delete the child items, or should I delete them myself?

The thing is, my deletion code works fine if I add a SaveChanges() before the DeleteObject, but if I attempt to delete first, THEN save changes, I tend to get some "Unable to determine the principal end of an association" -exceptions. This is now that I'm attempting something like this with EF 4. With EF5, I would just use the context.Local -property instead, but now I'm not quite certain on what EF 4 does with objects with entity state Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe changing the state of `newItem` to `Unchanged` will do the trick.

But I would take a different approach. Apparently you are in a process where it is decided which new items ultimately will be committed to the database. I would use a simple local `List<T>` of these items, and initially only add/remove items to and from this list. In the end, when everything has been sorted out, you add the remaining items to `myContext.Items` and save changes. It will also reduce overhead because the change tracker will be less busy.

Comment: Yes, well spotted, I totally forgot to explain that part of the process. Thing is, my actual case contains both old (read from the db) and new (recently created, not-yet-saved) entities. But even so, just keeping all the newly created items in a separate list from which I can delete them, and then going through the list before saving seems indeed like a sound option. Thanks!